# Trying to generate a week-timeline with PHP

Tags: php

I'm coding some kind of schedule and get stuck itterating trough the the dates.

I have a timeline generated for 5 work-days starting at 6:00h till 18:30h this is no problem. 
I have a table with users and a table with dates. The users can have multiple tasks during the week.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dateStart] => 2011-09-14 13:00:00
            [dateEnd] => 2011-09-15 11:00:00
            [eventType] => 1
            [data] => test
            [taskDescription] => Vakantieverlof
            [taskColor] => ff6600
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dateStart] => 2011-09-14 15:00:00
            [dateEnd] => 2011-09-14 18:00:00
            [eventType] => 3
            [data] => 
            [taskDescription] => ADV
            [taskColor] => 336600
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dateStart] => 2011-09-15 16:00:00
            [dateEnd] => 2011-09-16 10:00:00
            [eventType] => 2
            [data] => 
            [taskDescription] => Ziek
            [taskColor] => ff0000
        )
)
```

And this is the loop trough the array:

```
$dat=0;
while($dat<count($row->dates))
{
    $color = "cccccc";

    if(!empty($row->dates[$dat]['taskColor'])) {
        $color = $row->dates[$dat]['taskColor'];
        $desc = $row->dates[$dat]['taskDescription'];
    } else {
        $color = "cccccc";
    }
    $datNext = $dat+1;
    if($datNext >= count($row->dates)) $datNext = $dat;
    if($row->dates[$datNext]['dateStart'] >= $hourCons AND $dat >= count($row->dates))
    {
        $dat++;

    } else {
        if( $row->dates[$dat]['dateStart'] < $hourConsEnd AND $row->dates[$dat]['dateEnd'] > $hourCons )
        {
            $wpcal .= "<div class=\"fullCell\" style=\"".$transparent." background-color: #".$color.";\"></div>";

        } else {
            $wpcal .= "<div class=\"emptyCell\" style=\"\"></div>";


        }
    }
    $dat++;

}
```

Now I get 3 timelines representing each planned task. like this:

[Screenshot](http://www.websites-uit-limburg.nl/timeline-screenshot.png)

But I want 1 timeline containing each of these tasks... the green task in this case may overlap the orange.

Please help I'm strungling with it for a couple of days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array of appointments, loop through hours of the day for each day. Inside that loop, check if *any* of the appointments overlap that time, and draw filled if so.

```
$filled_flag = false;
foreach ($row->dates as $appt) {
  if ($appt['dateStart'] < $hourConsEnd && $appt['dateEnd'] > $hourCons) {
    $filled_flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
if ($filled_flag) {
  $wpcal .= "<div class=\"fullCell\" style=\"".$transparent." background-color: #".$color.";\"></div>";
} else {
  $wpcal .= "<div class=\"emptyCell\" style=\"\"></div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Didn't think of the break; Never used it before for this purpose!

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the arrays into one array first, before you loop through them generating the `<div>`s. For example you can precreate an array with all the 'slots', and then fill them with the most applicable task. In the `foreach` where you do the merge, you can apply some business logic, like if the task is completely overlapped by another one, overwrite its slots etc.

Comment: Can you give an example on merging the array... is it done with array_merge()?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually my Array is part of an object per user:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [username] => Emminet
    [user_level] => 100
    [dates] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [dateStart] => 2011-09-07 07:00:00
                    [dateEnd] => 2011-09-14 15:29:59
                    [eventType] => 3
                    [data] => Dit is dan veld 2...
                    [taskDescription] => ADV
                    [taskColor] => 336600
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [dateStart] => 2011-09-14 09:00:00
                    [dateEnd] => 2011-09-14 16:29:59
                    [eventType] => 3
                    [data] => dit is veld 1
                    [taskDescription] => ADV
                    [taskColor] => 336600
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [dateStart] => 2011-09-15 12:30:00
                    [dateEnd] => 2011-09-15 16:29:59
                    [eventType] => 3
                    [data] => 
                    [taskDescription] => ADV
                    [taskColor] => 336600
                )

        )

)
```

So I loop through the users and for every user I loop trough the week like this:

```
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
    // Timeframing settings
    $startDayAt = "06:00";
    $frameAmount = 26;
    $timeFrame = 30; // minutes
    // Timeframing output
    for($i=0,$eTime = strtotime($startDayAt); $i < $frameAmount; $i++, $eTime = strtotime("+$timeFrame minutes", $eTime)) { 

        $dat=0;
        while($dat<count($row->dates))
        {
            $color = "cccccc";

            if(!empty($row->dates[$dat]['taskColor'])) {
                $color = $row->dates[$dat]['taskColor'];
                $desc = $row->dates[$dat]['taskDescription'];
            } else {
                $color = "cccccc";
            }
            $datNext = $dat+1;
            if($datNext >= count($row->dates)) $datNext = $dat;
            if($row->dates[$datNext]['dateStart'] >= $hourCons AND $dat >= count($row->dates))
            {
                $dat++;

            } else {
                if( $row->dates[$dat]['dateStart'] < $hourConsEnd AND $row->dates[$dat]['dateEnd'] > $hourCons )
                {
                    $wpcal .= "<div class=\"fullCell\" style=\"".$transparent." background-color: #".$color.";\"></div>";

                } else {
                    $wpcal .= "<div class=\"emptyCell\" style=\"\"></div>";


                }
            }
            $dat++;

        }




}           
}
```

So that's my actual loop, trough the days and then the hours and later the users...